# "I found no \citation commands", I used backend=bibtex and also configured bibtex.exe

Tags: bibliographies

my previous question has not been solved. I had problem with TexMaker which told me "File not Found" when I open `Thesis.tex`. The question link is  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339701/file-not-found-which-i-have-ready-activated-pdflatex

I have opened my tex files with notepad and copied the script and created new tex files. Now when I compile the data, it come out the following errors:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9) The top-level auxiliary file: Thesis.aux 
I found no \citation commands---while reading file Thesis.aux 
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file Thesis.aux 
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file Thesis.aux 
(There were 3 error messages)
```

How can I solve this?
updated script, very short one, new error: I couldn't open file name `test.aux'

Thank you

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,
                style=authoryear,
                natbib=true, 
                style=numeric-comp
                ]{biblatex}    
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{document}  
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{ASH,
    author = {Seiffert, U. & Wech, L.},
    year = {2003},
    title = {Automotive Safety Handbook},
  }
\end{filecontents*}
Test of bibliography: 
This comes from \cite{ASH}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: You did not provide a compilable example. Does your document have any `cite` commands? Why are you using `bibtex` instead of `biber`?

Comment: Have you tried clearing all auxiliary files and start the compile chain again? `latex thesis`, `bibtex thesis`, `latex thesis`, `latex thesis`

Comment: I don't know how I can provide a proof that I used "cite" command. as the citation is in chapter but  not in the master file. My reference (Bib.bib) has been created by JabRef @Johannes_B

Comment: You are able to read german, right? http://golatex.de/wichtige-hinweise-erstellung-von-literaturverzeichnissen-t11964.html

Comment: @Johannes_B my English is better than my German. I can't read very fast and find the solution when I read long text in German.

Comment: make a small script in some test folder, which only loads the class, inputenc, fontenc, babel and biblatex, the \addbibresource{Bib.bib}, and a minimal text body with some citations. Try to get this working. It is madness to try out such things in a maximum document.

Comment: it makes sense to try with shorter script. but it has different error now. it can't find test.aux file. @UlrikeFischer

Comment: In your new code you need to move `\usepackage{filecontents}` to *before* `\begin{document}`. Also, there are certainly no `\cite{Knu86}` in that example. Final problem: With `biblatex` you should use `\printbibliography`, not `\bibliography{filename}`, and you should have `\addbibresource{filename.bib}` in the preamble (i.e. before `\begin{document}`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. thank you for the correction! but it still has the same error "I couldn't open file name `test.aux'"

Comment: @Johannes_B I have tried with your script from your link. It produces the same error: "I couldn't open file name `test.aux' ". And the test.aux is not in the folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Too long for a comment, but here is a working version of the code in your question:

Changes:

- Used `and` instead of `&` in the `author` entry. Authors should always be separated by the keyword `and`. And `&` alone will generate an error anyways, as it's an active character used as the column separator in tables and the like, so you need `\&` to print an ampersand in the text.
- `\Bib.bib` -> `\jobname.bib`.
- Added `\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}`. Note that it is added after the `filecontents` environment, to ensure that the file exists when `\addbibresource` looks for it.
- Added a citation to the only entry: `\cite{ASH}`.

If you get some errors about `.aux` file or similar, try deleting the `.aux` and the `.bbl` file, and then run `pdflatex`, `bibtex` and twice `pdflatex` again.

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,
                style=authoryear,
                natbib=true, 
                style=numeric-comp
                ]{biblatex}    
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{ASH,
    author = {Seiffert, U. and Wech, L.},
    year = {2003},
    title = {Automotive Safety Handbook},
  }
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}  
\cite{ASH}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! But the error is still there... I don't understand why because the test.aux is not in the folder at all, it's not even generated.In Tools->configuration->bib(la)tex "C:/Program Files (x86)/PortyTeX/portyTeX/MiKTeX_Portable/miktex/bin/bibtex.exe" %    Is that sth wrong here?

Comment: @Vivian The `.aux` file should be generated when you run `pdflatex`, you did that first right? If yes, read on. You're using Texmaker? Have you by any chance selected the option for "Use a build subdirectory for ouput files" in Options -> configure texmaker? If yes, unselect that option and try again.

Comment: First make sure you clean out all the old files before compiling. Basically you were missing the `\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}` command(which tells bibtex which .bib file to use) and you need to use \& rather than & alone in the bib entry.