# footcite doesn´t show full name of author

Tags: biblatex

I use TexMaker to write my thesis. 
I have a Bibliography in the end of my thesis, and inside the text, I also want to show footcite, but if I use \footcite, in footnote it only shows only last name of one author, but I need both authors´ full name. How can I solve this?

And the website link in the citation is too long, how to make line feed before a text end? As the website link goes out of the width of my defined text width.

Thank you

My script:

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage[a4paper, text={16.5cm, 25.2cm}, centering]{geometry}
    \usepackage[sfdefault]{ClearSans}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \setlength{\parskip}{1.2ex}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0em}
    \usepackage{filecontents}
    \usepackage[backend=bibtex,
            style=authortitle-comp,
            natbib=true, 
            ]{biblatex}
    \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Electronic{unintentional,
  Title                    = {Accidents or Unintentional Injuries},
  Author                   = {Altiok,Tayfur; Melamed, Benjamin},
  Note                     = {[Accessed on August 10, 2016]. Available on: \textcolor{blue}{http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/fastats/accidental-injury.htm}}
}

    \end{filecontents}
    \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
    \addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
    \begin{document}

    here is just a test \cite{unintentional} .

\printbibliography
   \end{document}
```

Comment: It is not unusual to give only last names in citations (`\footcite` and friends), often the full name is only given in the bibliography. Please note that `Author = {Altiok,Tayfur; Melamed, Benjamin},` is wrong, see [How should I type author names in a bib file?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/557/35864).

Comment: ...  Since you use `biblatex` you should do what you do with your `note` field (`Note = {[Accessed on August 10, 2016]. Available on: \textcolor{blue}{http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/fastats/accidental-injury.htm}}`) as follows: `urldate = {2016-08-10}`, `url={http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/fastats/accidental-injury.htm}`. `biblatex` will take care of everything else.

Comment: I realise you have been told some of that before: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/340310/35864. Maybe you should have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/35864 as well as one of the introductory guides suggested there. I happen to like http://dag.at.ifi.uio.no/public/doc/biblatex-guide.pdf

Comment: @samcarter I just noted you deleted your answer. I thought you might like edit your answer with the suggestions in my comment.

Comment: @moewe I also had other reasons to delete my answer, but please feel free to convert your comment into an answer. I will certainly upvote your non-hacky solution!

Comment: @samcarter OK, then. I have added a solution that I deem non-hacky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should give author names in the format explained in [How should I type author names in a bib file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/557/35864). That is, separate all authors by `and`.
Furthermore, you should use the `url` and `urldate` field instead of `note`.

```
@online{unintentional,
  title   = {Accidents or Unintentional Injuries},
  author  = {Altiok, Tayfur and Melamed, Benjamin},
  url     = {http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/fastats/accidental-injury.htm},
  urldate = {2016-08-10},
}
```

What you then want comes own to changing the `labelname` format, which is used in citations, and `sortname`, which is used in the bibliography, to

```
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{family-given}
```

Then you can get semicolons with

```
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}
```

---

Then

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authortitle-comp]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{unintentional,
  title   = {Accidents or Unintentional Injuries},
  author  = {Altiok, Tayfur and Melamed, Benjamin},
  url     = {http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/fastats/accidental-injury.htm},
  urldate = {2016-08-10},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{family-given}

\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}

\begin{document}
\cite{unintentional}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

gives

[image: example output]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried this solution, but in bibliography, it comes out " AltiokA.BenjaminB.Tayfur; MelamedT.M" as author name. What can be the reason for this? Can you add the complete script, so I can check what was wrong from my script? Thank you!

Comment: @Vivian I have added a full MWE. Did you get any errors or warnings in when you tried the solution?

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried your complete solution, but still have the same problem : author name is not correct, still get "AltiokA.BenjaminB.Tayfur; MelamedT.M"". And I tried again without labelname and sortname, then it works in bibliography, but not in cite

Comment: @Vivian As you can see it works for me. Maybe your `biblatex` is not up to date (the solution above will work for `biblatex` >= 3.3, the current version is 3.7). But you should get errors and warnings in that case. Of course if you leave out code, the output will not be as expected.